# Android: Howto dynamicly adjust constraint view layout apply to child's size

Tags: android, constraints

I have a ContraintLayout view, in which there are a label and a badge:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="@dimen/px350dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/px30dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/px50dp"
    android:text="123.00"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/label"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:text="Send"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

However, when label is too long, the badge will be push outside the container, it is not accepted.
[image]

One of the solution is to change badge's constraint to right-to-right-of-parent. The short is, in some scene, the distance is somewhat far, like this:
[image]

So, I need a solution to resolve such issue. As I wonder, the badge will close to label as far as possible, until it reach the edge. Needs your help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. In the custom view, relayout in onLayout event.

```
class TextLabelView : ConstraintLayout {
   ...
   override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)

        badgeCtl?.let {
            if ((this.width - textCtl.width) / 2  - it.marginLeft < it.width) {
                val x = this.width - it.width
                it.layout(x, 0, it.measuredWidth + x, it.measuredHeight)
            }
        }
    }
}
```